# Pandas merge with many conditionals and inconsistent data

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I have 2 datasets that contain NBA team stats, one is organized randomly by team 1 or team 2, while the other is organized by team 1 being at home and team 2 being away.

One dataset contains the stats and the other contains the betting data associated, and are not in the same shape and order.

This is the structure of the first dataset, with the money lines associated to each team in each game.

```
    Date_team1  ML_team1    Team.id_team1   Final_team1 Date_team2  ML_team2    Team.id_team2   Final_team2
0   2007-11-03   130        23.0            88          2007-11-03  -150        3.0           93
1   2007-11-04  -125        28.0            95          2007-11-04   105        2.0           98
2   2007-11-04  -300        13.0            115         2007-11-04   250        21.0         101
3   2007-11-04  -425        20.0            97          2007-11-04   355        18.0          93
4   2007-11-04  -160        16.0            88          2007-11-04   140        4.0           90
5   2007-11-04  -350        9.0             92          2007-11-04   290        1.0           91
6   2007-11-04  -215        8.0             88          2007-11-04   185        19.0          93
7   2007-11-04  -350        24.0            103         2007-11-04   290        6.0           92
8   2007-11-04  -115        14.0            119         2007-11-04  -105        29.0         109
```

This is the second dataset, with more of the results of the actual matchups.

```
    game.id team.id_team1   game.date_team1 pts_team1   team.id_team2   game.date_team2 pts_team2
41  21980   3               2007-11-03      65.0        23              2007-11-03      88.0
42  23273   2               2007-11-04      98.0        28              2007-11-04      95.0
43  22599   16              2007-11-04      88.0        4               2007-11-04      90.0
44  23409   13              2007-11-04      115.0       21              2007-11-04      101.0
45  21981   6               2007-11-04      92.0        24              2007-11-04      103.0
46  23138   14              2007-11-04      119.0       29              2007-11-04      109.0
47  22733   18              2007-11-04      93.0        20              2007-11-04      97.0
48  22872   1               2007-11-04      91.0        9               2007-11-04      92.0
49  24009   8               2007-11-04      88.0        19              2007-11-04      93.0
```

I am looking to merge the moneylines (**ML_team1 and ML_team2 columns**) alongside the stats of the second dataset, but given that the team1 teams are not consistent, I have been looking to find a way to first compare dates, and then compare within that date, is the **team.id** for the moneyline **team 1** or **team 2** and give that team the associated **moneyline**.

EDIT:

To be more clear, in the example dataset posted, *team1* in the first dataset is team *23*, which has an ML value 130, while in the second dataset, team 23 is labeled as *team 2*, and I want to add a column called 'ML_team2' which would have the value of 130 for this example.

The way the data has been collected has made it so that team1 and team2 in each dataset is not consistent.

What I have tried so far is this messy conditional:

```
    if full_df['Team.id_team1'] == stat_data['team.id_team1']:
        stat_data['ML_team1'] = full_df['ML_team1']
    else if full_df['Team.id_team1'] == stat_data['team.id_team2']:
        stat_data['ML_team2'] = full_df['ML_team1']
```

This code returned this error

`ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

Comment: Please be clear on what you want: *exactly* what is your "associated moneyline"?  Show examples.  Also post your coding progress, and ask a *specific* question.

Comment: Why are some ID columns float values, while others are int?  This inconsistency may cause you problems.

Comment: @Prune sorry I should have been more clear about Moneyline being the ML column in the first dataset posted. In terms of the specific question, I edited the post to specify a better example, and explain that I am looking to add ML_team1 and team2 columns to the stats of that associated team.

Answer (score 0):

There's an inconsistency with the pts too. In 1, team id 3 (2007-11-03) has 93 pts, and in the the other the same team id 3, same date recorded as 65 pts.

So I won't include that column, you can figure that part out.

But basically what I would do is I would stack the dataframes so each row is for each team, then you can merge on the team.id and dates:

```
import pandas as pd 


df1 = pd.DataFrame([['2007-11-03',   130,        23.0,            88,         '2007-11-03',  -150,        3.0 ,          93],
['2007-11-04',  -125 ,       28.0,            95 ,         '2007-11-04',   105,        2.0 ,          98],
['2007-11-04',  -300 ,       13.0,            115,         '2007-11-04',   250,        21.0,         101],
['2007-11-04',  -425 ,       20.0,            97 ,         '2007-11-04',   355,        18.0,          93],
['2007-11-04',  -160 ,       16.0,            88 ,         '2007-11-04',   140,        4.0 ,          90],
['2007-11-04',  -350 ,       9.0 ,            92 ,         '2007-11-04',   290,        1.0 ,          91],
['2007-11-04',  -215 ,       8.0 ,            88 ,         '2007-11-04',   185,        19.0,          93],
['2007-11-04',  -350 ,       24.0,            103,         '2007-11-04',   290,        6.0 ,          92],
['2007-11-04',  -115 ,       14.0,            119,         '2007-11-04',  -105,        29.0,         109]],columns=['Date_team1',  'ML_team1',    'Team.id_team1',   'Final_team1', 'Date_team2',  'ML_team2',    'Team.id_team2',   'Final_team2'])




df2 = pd.DataFrame([[21980,   3,               '2007-11-03',      65.0,        23,              '2007-11-03',      88.0],
[23273,   2 ,              '2007-11-04',      98.0 ,       28,              '2007-11-04',      95.0],
[22599,   16,              '2007-11-04',      88.0  ,      4 ,              '2007-11-04',      90.0],
[23409,   13,              '2007-11-04',      115.0 ,      21,              '2007-11-04',      101.0],
[21981,   6 ,              '2007-11-04',      92.0  ,      24,              '2007-11-04',      103.0],
[23138,   14,              '2007-11-04',      119.0 ,      29,              '2007-11-04',      109.0],
[22733,   18,              '2007-11-04',      93.0  ,      20,              '2007-11-04',      97.0],
[22872,   1 ,              '2007-11-04',      91.0  ,      9 ,              '2007-11-04',      92.0],
[24009,   8 ,              '2007-11-04',      88.0  ,      19,              '2007-11-04',      93.0]],columns=['game.id', 'team.id_team1',   'game.date_team1', 'pts_team1',   'team.id_team2',   'game.date_team2', 'pts_team2'])



rows = []
for x in ['1','2']:
    rows += df1[[col for col in df1.columns if x in col]].values.tolist()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=['game.date','ML_team','team.id','pts_team'])
df1 = df1.drop('pts_team',axis=1)


rows = []
for x in ['1','2']:
    rows += df2[['game.id'] + [col for col in df2.columns if x in col]].values.tolist()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=['game.id','team.id','game.date','pts_team'])
df2 = df2.drop('pts_team',axis=1)

df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['team.id','game.date'])
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
     game.date  ML_team  team.id  game.id
0   2007-11-03      130     23.0    21980
1   2007-11-04     -125     28.0    23273
2   2007-11-04     -300     13.0    23409
3   2007-11-04     -425     20.0    22733
4   2007-11-04     -160     16.0    22599
5   2007-11-04     -350      9.0    22872
6   2007-11-04     -215      8.0    24009
7   2007-11-04     -350     24.0    21981
8   2007-11-04     -115     14.0    23138
9   2007-11-03     -150      3.0    21980
10  2007-11-04      105      2.0    23273
11  2007-11-04      250     21.0    23409
12  2007-11-04      355     18.0    22733
13  2007-11-04      140      4.0    22599
14  2007-11-04      290      1.0    22872
15  2007-11-04      185     19.0    24009
16  2007-11-04      290      6.0    21981
17  2007-11-04     -105     29.0    23138
```